# How to get the page in a variable which is going to be displayed in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get the content which are displayed by a particular page in WordPress back-end.

Say, for `[ROOT]/wp-admin/profile.php`

I want to remove the First Name and Last Name fields from this page. So, I can run a `str_replace()` to remove the lines.

In this case, I have `$search` and `$replace` ... but I need `$subject` [Ref - http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php]

How to get the $subject ?

OR, anybody know any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the output buffer, to construct your page?

```
ob_start();
require_once(ABSPATH. 'wp-admin/profile.php');
$subject = ob_get_clean();
```

and then do a search and replace against that?

hope this helps :)